# Issue with If function

Tags: formula-field

I have three fields -

> Revised Budget - Currency(16,2)
>
> Probability (%) - Percent (18)
>
> Total Budgeted/Estimated - Currency (18)

Now I have a condition that if Revised budget field is empty then Perform the below calculation

> Probability Weighted Budget = Probability (%) * Total Budgeted/Estimated

If Revised Budget has a value then perform the below calculation.

> Probability Weighted Budget = Probability (%) * Revised Budget

Probability Weighted Budget is a formula field with currency return type.
I wrote the below mentioned formula in it but only half of the formula works. I tried ISNULL as well, no change. Kindly suggest.

Probability Weighted Budget:-

```
IF(ISBLANK(Revised_Budget__c) , Total_Budgeted__c * Probability__c, Revised_Budget__c * Probability__c )
```

Comment: Is revised budget a formula field? In that case you may have to change the way it handles blank fields. The standard setting is to treat blank fields as zero's but that is not always the desired setting.

Comment: Revised Budget is a currency field, Please check the description, I have already mentioned the fields name and data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can rewrite your formula as follows:

> BLANKVALUE(Revised_Budget__c, Total_Budgeted__c) * Probability__c

As for your primary problem, make sure that "Treat fields as blank" is selected; otherwise, Revised_Budget__c will be 0 instead of blank, and that will be used instead.